# Wordpress local site intergrate with live site

Tags: php, wordpress, html, integration

So i just want to know if the following is possible, and maybe if any help or links to any form of help is available.

**What i have/need** : I have a live site that i want to slowly start building over again, i want to integrate my local host custom theme site into the live site replacing the section i rebuild.

So i created my own custom theme WordPress website on my local and build a section of of my live website over. Its just because i want to slowly start building the whole live site over but starting at a point.

So now i want to integrate this section into my live wordpress site? That means replacing my current section with this new section.

Is this possible and how can i approach this?

Also i need the custom WP theme to stay as is even though i replaced it with the live section because my client can edit the site on his own with my custom theme.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Version Control for developing the new site.
choose any thing like svn /git. if you have not used anything like this, use hosted SVN, that's simple. something like assembla/beanstalk. anything.

Simply put all your WP code to trunk and create a branch from it. later you can merge the code to trunk.
you will create 2 hosts in your local for testing. 
you will checkout the code on your live server.